# How to post the data of chosen item in dropdown into a table

Tags: database, codeigniter, html-table

How do I put the information of the selected item in dropdown list into the table
like if I choose "chris" from the dropdown all of the details of chris that is on the database will be post in a table?
I would like to make it like this:

Select Customer:DropdownList  you will choose one from the dropdown after you select one there is a table below that will display further details of the one you have chosen

Firstname| LastName| Address

Chris    | Chris   | California

CONTROLLER

```
 public function salesorders() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
            $this->header2();
            $data['groups'] = $this->secretary_model->getAllGroups();
            $this->load->view('secretary/transactions',$data);
        } else {
            redirect('secretary/sec_login_view');
        }
    }
```

MODEL

```
function getAllGroups()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT firstname FROM tblcustomer');

        return $query->result();

    }
```

VIEW

```
<?php 
            echo "Select Customer";
            $options = array();
            foreach($groups as $group)
            { 
              $options[$group->firstname] = $group->firstname;
            }
            echo form_dropdown('dropdown', $options);
            ?>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" >  
                        <thead >  
                            <tr>  
                                 <th>Order #</th> 
                                 <th>Customer Name </th>  
                                <th>Items</th>  
                                <th>Note</th>  
                                <th>Qtt.</th> 
                                <th>Total Price</th> 
                                <th>Shipping Address</th> 
                                <th>Status</th>  
                                <th>Edit</th>  

                            </tr>  
                        </thead>  
                        <tbody>
```

Comment: Is the table shown before a selection is made? If so, with what data? If not, are you using css to hide it until a selection is made?

Comment: there is already a table shown without any datas inside

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well. I use this and Working fine

```
<ul>
    <?php    
        foreach($groups as $group)
        {
            ?>
            <li value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>"><?php echo $group['firstname']; ?></li>
        <?php    
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

in your model **change this** `$query = $this->db->query('SELECT firstname FROM tblcustomer');` **to this** `$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tblcustomer');`